# PHP curl equivalent to postman Follow Authorization header

Tags: php, curl, header, authorization

I am sending a request in Postman with the setting `Follow Authorization header` turned on. This request only works this way.

Unfortunately, the following request doesn't work in PHP. Is there an equivalent in PHP for the Postman `Follow Authorization header` setting?

This is the request that is not working:

```php
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'myurl',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
        "test":"test
      }',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Bearer mytoken',
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php: _"CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH: true to keep sending the username and password when following locations (using CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION), even when the hostname has changed."_ - this explicitly speaks of username and password, so I am not sure if it will also work for other types than HTTP Basic Auth, you'd have to test it. And if not - then you might have to set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to false, get the value of the `Location` header from the response, and then make a second request for that, supplying the authorization again explicitly.